# Consuming Kafka messages with its key in batches using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Is it somehow possible to get the key of the kafka message when [consuming them as batches](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_consuming_batches)?

I managed to access the message key when using `Message<String>` as input of my consumer function, but this only works in non-batch-mode:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class KafkaSink {

    private val log = logger()

    @Bean
    fun sink() : Consumer<Message<String>> {
        return Consumer {
            log.info("key: ${it.headers[KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY]} value: ${it.payload}")      
        }
    }
}
```

When setting the property `spring.cloud.stream.binding.sink.consumer.batch-mode=true` I can only use `List<String>` as argument for the consumer but not `List<Message<String>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Message<List<String>>`; then, the `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY` is a `List<?>` in the same order as the payloads - same thing for all other headers.

**EDIT**

Re comment below; the default content-type is `application/json`. Adding

```yaml
      bindings:
        sink-in-0:
          content-type: text/plain
```

fixes your test.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not make this work. In batch mode only `List<String>` works, when using `Message<List<String>>` there is some strange JSON conversion happening which leads to null values in the list as you can see in my [example](https://github.com/m-kay/kafka-batch-consumer/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/com/github/mkay/KafkaHttpSink.kt) when running the [test](https://github.com/m-kay/kafka-batch-consumer/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/com/github/mkay/KafkaHttpSinkTests.kt#L37)

Comment: Looks like some kind of inconsistency in Spring Cloud Function; the default content-type is `application/json`; I am not sure why it works ok with `List<String>` when setting the content type to `text/plain` it works ok. See my edit - I'll ping the SCF folks.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2258

Answer (score 0):

It is not mentioned anywhere unfortunately :-(, but to wrap input events into `org.springframework.messaging.Message` (to get record keys for example), here is the correct signature when doing batch processing:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<List<String>>> sink() {
    return messages -> {
        List<?> keys = messages.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, List.class);
        log.info("headers {}", messages.getHeaders());
        keys.forEach(k -> log.info("key {}", k));
        messages.getPayload().forEach(string -> log.info("processing {}", string));
    };
}
```

You notice that is the signed the other way around: `Message<List<?>>` rather than `List<Message<?>>`!